# Suppose a fair coin is flipped five times in a row. (a) What is the probability of getting all five heads?

Tags: probability

Suppose a fair coin is flipped five times in a row.

(a) What is the probability of getting all five heads?

(b) What is the probability of getting at least one tail?

My attempt:

(a)

Sample space = $2^5$

Event space = $\{H, H, H, H, H\} = 5$

$$\frac{|E|}{|S|} = \frac{5}{2^5}$$

(b)

Sample space = $2^5$

Event space = no idea

Could someone help me on this please.

Comment: If you have no idea, why not try this with three coins instead? Then the sample space has size 8 and it's easy to write out all the possibilities. It will guide you towards the result. Alternatively, writing out 32 possible configurations would probably take less time than typing up this question :)

Comment: Your event space in both cases is the set of sequences of length 5 drawn from {H, T}.

Comment: In the first question, there is only one sequence with five heads.  What is the complement of at least one tail?

Comment: 1-1/32 is my guess. And a should be 1/32 now that I think of it yeah

Comment: @rebelion **See T. Bongers comment.**  The *underlying* problem is that you need to develop your **intuition**, and the tried and true way of doing that is by **manually** examining simple cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample space is $\sf\{H,T\}^5$, and there are indeed $2^5$ elements in this set.   The sample space may also be expressed as $\sf\{(H,H,H,H,H),(H,H,H,H,T),\ldots,(T,T,T,T,T)\}$.

Although it has five members in itself, the ordered pentuple, $\sf (H,H,H,H,H)$, is itself just **one** element in the sample space; that is, it is one from among the thirty two ordered pentuples in the sample set.   As the elements (or atomic outcomes) of the sample space are *all equally probable*, the probability for the event of "all heads" is $2^{-5}$ or $1/32$.

---

Now consider that the event of "at least one tail" is the complement of "all heads".   The events are mutually exclusive, and exhaustive.